# Why does let --n have an exit code different from let n-- in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

Why do these have an exit code of 1?

```
n=1
let --n
```

And why does this have exit code of 0?

```
n=1 
let n--
```

This has exit code of 1 too... why?

```
n=1
let "n = n - 1"
```

Comment: Just curious , why was this question given a negative vote ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

man bash says:

```
let arg [arg ...]
          Each arg is an arithmetic expression to be evaluated (see ARITH‐
          METIC EVALUATION above).  If the last arg evaluates  to  0,  let
          returns 1; 0 is returned otherwise.
```

1 - 1 = 0, therefore the exit code is 1.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between `--n` and `n--` is that the first term has the value `n-1` (it's decremented *first* and then evaluated) while the second term has the value `n` (post decrement). *After* the value is taken, n is always one less but the position of the `--` says when the value should be copied into the result.